# Right way to write Unit Tests in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Probably going down the rabbit hole, but its worth asking on StackOverflow and getting opinions from experts.

What is the correct way to write a unit test? Specifically, if we have a function to unit test, which in turn calls one or more other functions from the same project...
Shall those other two function calls be mocked?

**Example:**

Unit Test:

```
[Test]
  public void ReadZipFileContainer_Test()
  {
     AClass aObject = new AClass();
     string fileToRead = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\..\TestData\TestFile.zip");
     List<string> entityIds = new List<string>() { UtilsClass.kItemId };
     Dictionary<string, string> filesData1 = AClass.ReadFileContainer(fileToRead, entityIds);
     Assert.AreEqual(filesData1.Count, 1);
  }
```

In AClass:

```
  public Dictionary<string, string> ReadZipFileContainer(string fileToRead, List<string> itemIds)
  {         
     Dictionary<string, string> fileContent = new Dictionary<string, string>();         
     try
     {
        Dictionary<string, string> entities = CClass.OpenContainer(fileToRead); // => call to another function. Should this call be mocked?
        //Process         
     }         
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // We return empty directory after closing the container
        logger.LogException(ex);
        throw;
     }
     finally
     {
        CClass.CloseContainer();
     }         
     return fileContent;
  }
```

Each individual has personal opinion, but I am looking for the best practice. How to decide the line where we need to stop mocking?

Comment: well that sucks... wrote out something and post got locked :O  I don't think the bread and butter of the question is opinion based - a unit test is a test for a single unit.  If your unit depends on concretions, then it can by definition not be a unit test, as it relies on something external to the unit.  dependencies need to be abstracted so they can be mocked in order to accomplish a unit test.

Comment: there are some pretty strict rules which define unit testing and how to write unit testing. Those are not really opinion based. Just my 2c .

Answer (score 2):

Wow, such a huge topic ... well let's cover a few things :).

there are a few rules to follow if

1. you want your code to be testable
2. Want to write decent Unit tests

Rules : never ever use hardcoded dependencies in your classes, always use abstractions and always use DI to inject dependencies. That's what helps you when you need to mock things and it also helps you when you need to change things.

Unit testing : there are a few basic rules here such as :

your unit tests should not touch a real system, meaning file on disk, external api, database etc. The reason is that you will end up with a lot of unit tests and you want them to be very quick, not take 20 minutes to complete. A lot of teams have rules such as they never accept code commits unless the code is covered by unit tests and all existing unit tests still pass. Do you want to wait 20 minutes every time you commit?

Make sure that your tests do not share state, your tests need to be able to run independently and not rely on stuff set up or changed by a previous test.

You can't imagine how many times I've seen unit tests which do not assert anything.

There is a lot more of course but if you stick to these basic principles you should be fine.

Comment: You probably are also going to see your code start to reflect SOLID principles more if you do it write.  You'll start extracting interfaces and decoupling components so that you can fake the various parts of your system.